# EC2 AMI SSH broken due to home folder permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

Oy.  It's Monday.

I ran these commands so php would have access to some files a cron was writing to the home folder:

```
chown ec2-user:apache /home/ec2-user
chmod 2775 /home/ec2-user
# the owner of /home/ec2-user used to be root:root.  I intended to change to root:apache, but copy/pasted this line from somewhere and didn't proofread.
```

Things continued ok until my connections have closed and now I can't SSH into the server anymore.  Error is `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`

Any ideas to regain access to the server?

This is an Amazon Linux 2 instance on AWS.

Comment: I see articles like this one recommending mounting the drive to a new/accessible instance.  Except running chown is not an option because the UIDs won't match up  http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root

Comment: Maybe if I connect the drive to another instance, I could put something in a startup file so on bootup, it corrects the owner of the root folder?   Then simply put instance/drive back as it was and turn it on?  Where would that command go?

Comment: If your AMI has the aws SSM agent installed you can remote execute shell commands via System manager on the aws console, otherwise as efreed suggests mount the disk in another machine.

Comment: @MisterSmith, want to post an answer on that one?  Where in Systems Manager can I send an ad-hoc command?

Comment: @efred if you can mount the ec2 drive, you CAN change the permissions - the root account should always match uid 0. If you need other users you canget the userid from the third column of the passwd file at /mountpoint/etc/passwd and then use chmod with numbers rather then names. (its also not impossible that in a typical install will have the same uid for preinstalled users)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved it (thanks to the System Manager comment by @MisterSmith):

- Visit "AWS System Manager" > Automation
- Search for `AWSSupport-TroubleshootSSH` and select it.
- Pick the instance (I had to change the "Show managed instances"
  selection to "Show all instances)
- Change action to "Check All" and Allow Offline to "True" and then
  Execute
- (A stop/start of the instance was performed as part of the Execution)

Result Output:

```
----------[Diagnostic Results]----------

module run/openssh               [SUCCESS] All configuration checks passed or all detected problems fixed.
                                 -- FIXED       Permission mode includes write for groups and/or other users: /home/ec2-user
                                 -- FIXED       Missing authorized key directory: /home/ssm-user/.ssh
                                 -- FIXED       Missing authorized key file: /home/ssm-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
                                 -- FIXED       Permission mode includes permissions for groups and/or other users: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
                                 -- FIXED       Permission mode includes permissions for groups and/or other users: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
                                 -- FIXED       Permission mode includes permissions for groups and/or other users: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

I tested SSH access and everything is working as before!

Curiously, the home folder **owner** was unchanged.  Something else in the above output fixed things.

```
ls -hal of /home/ec2-user in broken state:
drwxrwsr-x 7 ec2-user apache   4.0K May 18 06:59
ls -hal in repaired state:
drwxr-sr-x 7 ec2-user apache   4.0K May 18 06:59
```

Comment: Fantastic. Worked for me. Thanks @efreed